# ¿Cómo hacer que este símbolo | sea más grande en LaTex?

Tags: latex

me podrían ayudar a que la barra vertical se vea más grande, por ejemplo en este caso

```
\[D_{f \circ g} = \left\{x\in \mathbb{R}-3|\frac{2}{x-3} \in \mathbb{R}\right\}\]
```

[image: Ahí la barra vertical se ve muy pequeña]

Intenté usar \left | pero aunque efectivamente se hace más grande arroja un error, supongo que será porque no puse ningún \right pero no sabría a que ponérselo.

Hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo. Espero que me puedan ayudar ya que aun soy un principiante.

Answer (score 3):

Hay 2 soluciones fáciles:

1. Usando `\left` y `\right`
   [image: ejemplo_con_lefT_right]

   ```
   \[D_{f \circ g} = \left\{x\in \mathbb{R}-3\left|\frac{2}{x-3} \in \mathbb{R}\right.\right\}\]
   ```

   En este caso basta con usar `\left. \right|` o bien `\left| \right.`, pues el `.` sirve para marcar que no habrá un delimitador, aquí un ejemplo:

   [image: ejemplo_letf_right]

   ```
     \[\left.\frac{a}{b}\right| \qquad \left|\frac{a}{b}\right.\]
   ```
2. Usando `\biggm`:
   [image: ejemplo_con_biggm]

   ```
   \[D_{f \circ g} = \left\{x\in \mathbb{R}-3\biggm|\frac{2}{x-3} \in \mathbb{R}\right\}\]
   ```

   Pero en esta opción es que tienes que *ajustar*  al tamaño deseado con `\big`, `\Big`,`\Bigg`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

El truco podría ser establecer el tamaño de la matriz, por ejemplo a 3 filas y una columna:

```
\left.\begin{matrix}
\\ 
\\ 
\end{matrix}\right|
```

Lo que podrías incorpora a tu formula:

```
\[D_{f \circ g} = \left\{x\in \mathbb{R}-3\left.\begin{matrix}\\\\\end{matrix}\right|\frac{2}{x-3} \in \mathbb{R}\right\}\]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]